# How to assign and send ether value together with deployment of contract using Foundry

Tags: solidity, ether, foundry, test, forge

This is the simple function, how do I deploy the contract and send ether along with it?

```
    function setUp() public {
        test = new testContract(
            Owner;
        );
    }
```

Comment: where do you wanna send ethers and why?

Comment: @TalhaSajidChaudhary some use cases require users to send ether along with their contact during deployment.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your `constructor` is marked `payable`, you can modify your test like this:

```
function setUp() public {
        test = new testContract{value: 777}(
            Owner;
        );
    }
```

You can ensure that the ETH was sent by adding a test like this:

```
function test_balance() public {
     uint bal = address(test).balance;
     assertEq(bal, 100);
}
```